# Script run before LiveCycle transformPDF service

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer

I am having a problem with the transformPDF service. Basically, script is being run in the docReady of the PDF that I am trying to flatten. The script is throwing an error in the logs, but returns a flattened PDF, with some values missing. The script that is running is meant for and runs fine when the client opens the pdf, but I do not want this code running when I send it to transformPDF. In other words, the PDF I send transformPDF is the PDF I want flattened, without any further processing being done to it. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving the script in `docReady` into `initialise` step, and use "Run on Server" for the scripts.